# How i can hide keyborad on event in bada webapp?

Tags: web-applications, keyboard, bada

I need hide keyboard on event in my BADA webapp, and i can't find info in developer api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pKeyboard->HideKeypad(); 
I don't know if it works for you though, cause I tried the HideKeypad method and it works for my editfield. :)